# What's more effective at blowing out a candle? High pressure, or high speed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, speed, flow

I have an assignment that requires me to build a robot that can blow out a candle.

I'm investigating ways in which I can do this, and blowing on it with a fan seems like a decent approach. However, I'm unsure whether I should seek out a fan with high mass flow rate, high exit velocity, or high pressure.

From my understanding, it is the speed of a gust of air that causes the flame front to detach from the fuel source (paraffin vapor) which ultimately puts it out. This leads me to believe that I should be seeking out a fan with a high flow rate. Is this correct?

Also, could I employ a nozzle to improve it further?

Comment: *"This leads me to believe that I should be seeking out a fan with a high flow rate. Is this correct?"* Your reasoning is correct: flow rate is what matters here. A suitable nozzle might increase that further.

Comment: @Gert What do you have in mind for a "suitable" nozzle?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html. Restricting the cross section increases $v$. It might be what you need.

Comment: I don't see the difference between "high mass flow rate, high exit velocity, or high pressure" because one implies the other.

Comment: @Deep High exit velocity and high pressure imply high mass flow rate, but saying that a fan has high mass flow rate doesn't indicate whether that's by having a high exit velocity, a high pressure, or some middle ground of both

Comment: Unless you are assuming compressible flow (which is not necessary in your case) mass flow rate per unit area ($\rho\mathbf{u}$) and flow velocity ($\mathbf{u}$) differ only by a prefactor (which is density, $\rho$). Also higher the static pressure of the fan higher the flow rate it can achieve.

Comment: You'll need a fan with a high exit velocity and a decent flow rate. Sorry for the arbitrary amounts but to cut out the flame you'll need to isolate the flame from the fuel source, and a high flow rate with a low velocity will feed the flame even more!